# Unsubscribe to an event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm subscribing to an event this way:

```
  s1.MouseUp += (s, e) =>
  {
  indexOfPointToMove = -1;
  s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
  MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);
   e.Handled = true;
 };
```

How could I unsubscribe in different scope?  (but in scope of `s1`)

I've tried the following:

```
s1.MouseUp = null;



s1.MouseUp -=(s,e) =>
 {
       indexOfPointToMove = -1;
       s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
       MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);
       e.Handled = true;
  };



s1.MouseUp += (s,e) =>
{
//nothing
};
```

But the event is still firing, how can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use lambda to create anonymous event handler.

```
s1.MouseUp += s1_MouseUp; //subscribe
s1.MouseUp -= s1_MouseUp; //ussubscribe


private void s1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   var s1 = (ListBox)sender; //cast it to proper object
   indexOfPointToMove = -1;
   s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
   MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't subscribe to an event that way because I'm inside a loop in a method! And I can't create it outside because I can't reference s1. What can be done here?

Comment: @Sturm Do you mean that the compiler is capturing some local variables so that this example doesn't compile? If so, which one(s)?

Comment: Check my edited answer. You can access `s1` in event by casting `sender` to proepr object

Answer (score 7):

Do not use anonymous events but named ones.

```
 s1.MouseUp += Mouse_Up;

 s1.MouseUp -=Mouse_Up;

 void Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs ea)
 {  
    indexOfPointToMove = -1;   
    s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;  
    MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);    
    e.Handled = true;  
 }
```

Comment: +1 for being 30 sec faster :)

Comment: Thanks, I would be even faster if I hadn't clicked the wrong button :)

Comment: @keyboardP This is just the opposite from your signature answer :-D

Comment: So many choices :D Hadn't realised how many answers came up whilst I was typing!

Comment: Thank you! But I'm having troubles to implement this inside the loop I'm creating the events. I can't create them at class scope because I don't have access to s1 because it's a local variable inside the loop. What can I do?

Comment: Then go for the @Jon's answer, it should help you to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Yes and @gzaxx's answer is even better now when it is edited. You can cast the sender object to the type that emits the event,hence you can get the instance of the control that emitted the Mouse_Up event.

Answer (score 3):

You must make sure to unsubscribe the same handler you are subscribing, for example:

```
MouseEventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
{
    indexOfPointToMove = -1;
    s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
    MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);
    e.Handled = true;
};

s1.MouseUp += handler;
```

And later on:

```
s1.MouseUp -= handler; // you must have kept a reference to this somewhere
```

Of course if you are going to do this, it's probably much easier to simply use a member method in the first place as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This won't unsubscribe the event because anonymous methods are not guaranteed to compile into exactly the same thing, this affects equality checks on event unsubscribing causing them to "fail" to remove the subscription.

Anonymous methods are not like anonymous types where the compiler will use the same definition of a type if the type already exists.

Make the event handler a regular method, or store the anonymous method in a local variable and unsubscribe from that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a lambda (because of the execution context of the event), you can do it this way :

```
var act = new Action<object, EventArgs>((e, s) =>
    {
        indexOfPointToMove = -1;
        s1.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
        MyModel.RefreshPlot(false);
        e.Handled = true;
    });

this.MouseUp += act;

...

this.MouseUp -= act;
```